# Preserve string with spaces on read command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

So I have a command that output a comma delimited strings

Like this one;

```
"Name","Type","FC Ports","iSCSI Ports","User Group","Cluster","Performance Class"
"mnlas-esxq01","default","100000051EC20A95,100000051EC20A96,100000051EC21AC3,100000051EC21AC4","","","MNLASDMZ CL-1","none"
"mnlas-esxa02","default","100000051EC20D3A,100000051EC20D3B,100000051EC2218D,100000051EC2218E","","","MNLASDMZ CL-1","none"
"mnlas-esx916","default","21000024FF4DDC20,21000024FF4DDC21,21000024FF490CFC,21000024FF490CFD","","","MNLASPRODSCCM CL-1","none"
"mnlas-esx417","default","21000024FF4DDBE8,21000024FF4DDBE9,21000024FF490F56,21000024FF490F57","","","MNLASPRODSCCM CL-1","none"
"mnlas-esx111","default","21000024FF4DDC56,21000024FF4DDC57,21000024FF490F00,21000024FF490F01","","","MNLASPRODSCCM CL-1","none"
"mnlas-p-xca09.pr.int.ptc.com","default","21000024FF514CF4,21000024FF514CF5","","","MNLAS P-xca CL-1","none"
"mnlas-p-xca10.pr.int.ptc.com","default","21000024FF514ED2,21000024FF514ED3","","","MNLAS P-xca CL-1","none"
"mnlas-p-xca11.pr.int.ptc.com","default","21000024FF514FB6,21000024FF514FB7","","","MNLAS P-xca CL-1","none"
"mnlas-esx403.ad.cibc.com","default","10008C7CFF702490,10008C7CFF702491,10008C7CFF702494,10008C7CFF702495,10008C7CFF652604,10008C7CFF652605,10008C7CFF20D0A8,10008C7CFF20D0A9","","","MNLASPRODSQL CL-1","none"
"mnlas-esx401.ad.cibc.com","default","10008C7CFF702484,10008C7CFF702485,10008C7CFF7023F4,10008C7CFF7023F5,10008C7CFF21B3E8,10008C7CFF21B3E9,10008C7CFF65203E,10008C7CFF65203F","","","MNLASPRODSQL CL-1","none"
```

As you can see lengths are also different.

My objective is to echo Name, iSCSI Ports and Cluster but sometimes some of the fields are empty as well.

How can i properly format it and use grep to find the hostname that will look like this.

```
Name            iSCSI Ports                               Cluster
mnlas-esxq01    100000051EC20A95,100000051EC20A96         MNLASDMZ CL-1
```

btw, iSCSI Ports tend to be a bit longer due to the number of ports so CLuster field should adjust

I tried using this command but it didn't work. It says

```
sh-4.2# cat temp/testS | grep -i esx401 | while read "Name" "Type" "iSCSI Ports" "User Group" "Cluster" "Performance Class";do echo $Name $"iSCSI Ports" $Cluster;done
sh: read: `iSCSI Ports': not a valid identifier
```

I also tried defining it to a variable but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to provide some sample input that actually has some non-empty iSCSI values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the definition of a "name", which the shell uses for variables and function names:

> `name`
>
> > A word consisting **solely of letters, numbers, and underscores**, and beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell variable and function names. Also referred to as an identifier.

[2 Definitions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Definitions)

You are not allowed to use spaces in a variable name.

Given that, CSV files are sometimes quite tricky to work with. Tricky enough that you should be using a proper CSV parser. [csvkit](/questions/tagged/csvkit) is a good suite of tools:

```
csvcut -c "Name,iSCSI Ports,Cluster" file.csv
```

Comment: is that the only available option?

Comment: The only available option to parse CSV files? No, certainly not. It's the first one that came to mind. I like to use ruby's csv module for one-liners. Perl's Text::CSV module is very robust, particularly when you might get newlines inside a quoted field, but it's a little bit unwieldy to workwith. You can do your own research at this point to find something that works for you, and you can come back to SO to ask *specific* questions about your implementation.

Comment: Native bash is not a good choice for parsing CSV. Regex-based tools like sed are not a good choice. There is a way to use awk and [the FPAT variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content).

Answer (score 1):

When you don't want to use a csv parser and don't have double quotes inside your fields, you can try the next work-around:

```
while IFS=$'\r' read -r name type fcports scsi user cluster remainer; do
   printf "%-40s %-20s %-20s\n" "${name}" "${scsi}" "${cluster}"
   # or use ${fcports} to show output like your example
done < <(sed 's/","/\r/g' file.csv | tr -d '"')
```

Comment: Never mind -- those were quote delimited fields containing commas... (good work-around approach)

Comment: @Walter A,

So i tried your solutions and got this error. btw, i'm searching the hostname to a multiple files so i have to use grep.

` grep -i $host ${XIV_TEMP_DIR}/*-*XIV-* | while IFS=$'\r' read -r  Name Type FC Ports iSCSI Ports User Group Cluster Performance Class; do printf "%-40s %-20s %-20s\n" "${Name}" "${FC Ports}" "${Cluster}" done < <(sed 's/","/\r/g' ${XIV_TEMP_DIR}/*-*XIV-* | tr -d '"') `

Comment: As explained by @glennjackman do not use spaces in the names of your variables. And (not an error now) use lowercase names (uppercase names are reserved for the OS).